# java spring jsp model attributes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

i have model which contains property:

```
public BigDecimal amount
```

when i return it to view its value is setted to 55. in JSP page i have written Amount:

```
`${amount}`
```

Result is correct. But i want to divide it to 100 before showing. But i want to do it on jsp only. i am now writing so:

`${amount/100}`. But result is not correct. it rounds it and result is **1**. how to do it so that it returned **0.55**

Comment: instead of 100 use 100.0

Comment: try typecasting to float as {(float)amount/100}

Comment: Error on parsing. i can not include (float) to this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use two attributes

```
    m.addAttribute("amount", new BigDecimal("55"));
    m.addAttribute("divisor", new BigDecimal("100"));
```

Then you do this

```
${amount.divide(divisor)}
```

Another way is to use a class that extends the `BigDecimal`, say `MyBigDecimal` and define a method that does the division.

```
public class MyBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {

    public MyBigDecimal(String val) {
        super(val);
    }

    public String print() {
        return divide(new BigDecimal("100")).toPlainString();
    }

}
```

Then you do this.

```
 m.addAttribute("amount", new MyBigDecimal("55"));
 ${amount.print()}
```

You can also use custom JSTL functions but I don't fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this JSTL

```
     <fmt:formatNumber pattern="2" value="${amount/100}" var="cellData"/>
${cellData}
```

Comment: it returns -21. please test yourself before